# How to fix 'undefined method error' when method exists?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am new to Ruby on Rails and I'm getting this error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `comment' for #<Contact:0x000000001057cac8>
```

I've looked online and seen a lot of posts about `has_many` but I don't think that is what is wrong with mine as I am not trying to create a comments thread.

My contacts_controller.rb:

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @contact = Contact.new
  end

  def create
    @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)

    if @contact.save
      name = params[:contact][:name]
      email = params[:contact][:email]
      body = params[:contact][:body]

      ContactMailer.contact_email(name, email, body).deliver

      flash[:success] = "Message sent."
      redirect_to new_contact_path
    else
      flash[:danger] = "Message not sent."
      redirect_to new_contact_path
    end
  end

  private

  def contact_params
    params.require(:contact).permit(:name, :email, :comment)
  end
end
```

and my contacts form:

```
<div class="row">
  <%= form_for @contact do |f| %>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
      <div class="well">
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :name %>
          <%= f.text_field :name, class: "form-control" %>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :email %>
          <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :comment %>
          <%= f.text_area :comment, class: 'form-control' %>
        </div>

        <%= f.submit 'Submit', class: "btn btn-success btn-lg" %>
      </div>
    </div>

  <% end %>
</div>
```

My model, contact.rb:

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :email, presence: true
  validates :comment, presence: true
end
```

My database stuff:

```
class CreateContacts < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :contacts do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :email
      t.text :comment

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I used the Heroku CLI to manage mt apps and this is the output when I run `rake db:migrate`

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: Including LoggerSilence is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 6.1. Please use `ActiveSupport::LoggerSilence` instead (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/application.rb:7)
   (1.1ms)  SELECT pg_try_advisory_lock(1634294230270099020)
   (1.5ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
  ActiveRecord::InternalMetadata Load (1.6ms)  SELECT "ar_internal_metadata".* FROM "ar_internal_metadata" WHERE "ar_internal_metadata"."key" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["key", "environment"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (1.2ms)  SELECT pg_advisory_unlock(1634294230270099020)
```

Also, this worked fine on my localhost but not on Heroku. It is Heroku that is giving me the error and I don't know why.

What I've tried(keep in mind that I'm new to RoR):

1. Made sure the same version working on the localhost is what I pushed to Heroku.
2. Made sure it isn't an issue from my routes.
3. Reset the database.
4. Made sure spelling is consistent.

The error I am getting from my Heroku Logs:

```
2019-09-12T11:05:54.009358+00:00 app[web.1]: [a382e524-adf1-462b-bff6-bd6cba881a7c] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 226ms (ActiveRecord: 32.0ms | Allocations: 15274)
2019-09-12T11:05:54.011555+00:00 app[web.1]: [a382e524-adf1-462b-bff6-bd6cba881a7c]
2019-09-12T11:05:54.011558+00:00 app[web.1]: [a382e524-adf1-462b-bff6-bd6cba881a7c] ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `comment' for #<Contact:0x000055682aab6110>
2019-09-12T11:05:54.011561+00:00 app[web.1]: Did you mean?  comments
2019-09-12T11:05:54.011563+00:00 app[web.1]: comments=
2019-09-12T11:05:54.011565+00:00 app[web.1]: comments?):
2019-09-12T11:05:54.011567+00:00 app[web.1]: [a382e524-adf1-462b-bff6-bd6cba881a7c]     14:
2019-09-12T11:05:54.011570+00:00 app[web.1]: [a382e524-adf1-462b-bff6-bd6cba881a7c]     15:         <div class="form-group">
2019-09-12T11:05:54.011572+00:00 app[web.1]: [a382e524-adf1-462b-bff6-bd6cba881a7c]     16:           <%= f.label :comment %>
2019-09-12T11:05:54.011575+00:00 app[web.1]: [a382e524-adf1-462b-bff6-bd6cba881a7c]     17:           <%= f.text_area :comment, class: 'form-control' %>
2019-09-12T11:05:54.011577+00:00 app[web.1]: [a382e524-adf1-462b-bff6-bd6cba881a7c]     18:         </div>
2019-09-12T11:05:54.011579+00:00 app[web.1]: [a382e524-adf1-462b-bff6-bd6cba881a7c]     19:
2019-09-12T11:05:54.011581+00:00 app[web.1]: [a382e524-adf1-462b-bff6-bd6cba881a7c]     20:         <%= f.submit 'Submit', class: "btn btn-dark btn-block" %>
2019-09-12T11:05:54.011583+00:00 app[web.1]: [a382e524-adf1-462b-bff6-bd6cba881a7c]
2019-09-12T11:05:54.011586+00:00 app[web.1]: [a382e524-adf1-462b-bff6-bd6cba881a7c] app/views/contacts/new.html.erb:17
2019-09-12T11:05:54.011588+00:00 app[web.1]: [a382e524-adf1-462b-bff6-bd6cba881a7c] app/views/contacts/new.html.erb:2
```

Comment: How would you support your claim that the method exists? Why don't you show `Contact` model source?

Comment: Hey @Beulah, can you show us the  schema?

Comment: I have added tthem.

Comment: @BeulahAkindele Can you check the table on heroku? Use `heroku pg:psql` command to connect to the database.

Comment: It doesn't exist.`The local psql command could not be located. For help installing psql, see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#local-setup
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're having column rename issue. It is not recommended to reset the database because:

- Other environment or people has already run the old migration and if you use your current methods you have to inform everyone to do the same on every environment (`heroku` in this case)
- By resetting the database you will lose your data, we might be able to do so for development or testing but not production data.

What you should do is to create another migration file in order to rename the column, therefore when pulling the change, `Rails` will detect the new file and ask you to run `rake db:migrate` and problem solved.

```
def up
  # rename_column :contacts, :old_column, :new_column
  rename_column :contacts, :comments, :comment
end
```

Comment: Did you try to restart dyno as well?

Comment: I forgot if it's required us to restart the dyno or redo the deployment or not after the migration, because normally the server doesn't pickup the change like in local, please try to restart the dyno or just redeploy if you already run the migration. I used to have this exact same issue when I first use Heroku.

Comment: which of the method above, do you use for running migration? Did you notice the output? and can you try again and share the output?

Comment: I used the CLI.

Comment: I notice in your schema you have column `comment` and not `comments`, so please check your typo.

Comment: I have done that... the error simply changed to `undefined method `comment'`.

Comment: so your real column is `comment`?

Comment: you can try to debug by `heroku run rails console`, `Contact.new` and share with me the output. That way we can be sure if the column is already there or not.

Comment: I just got this: `Contact Load (3.2ms)  SELECT "contacts".* FROM "contacts" LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 11]]`.

Comment: But the Contact.column_names: `Loading production environment (Rails 6.0.0)
irb(main):001:0> Contact.column_names
=> ["id", "name", "email", "comments", "created_at", "updated_at"]
`.

Comment: You were right about rerunning the migration, however, for Heroku `heroku run db:migrate` won't reset the database, the way we'd want. I had to use `pg:reset` and follow the on-screen prompts to remove the database, then run 'heroku run db:migrate' to recreate it with the proper names. If you would edit your answer for anyone's future reference... I'll accpet your answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `has_many` association in this code. There is only text field for comment. If you use `comment` instead of `comments`, you won't get an error.

in controller:

```
def contact_params
  params.require(:contact).permit(:name, :email, :comment)
end
```

and view:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :comment %>
  <%= f.text_area :comment, class: 'form-control' %>
</div>
```

If you want to create a `has_many` association, check out the rails guide: [has_many association](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-association)

Comment: there is no need to change the "f.label :comments" :)

Comment: @BeulahAkindele What error do you get when you try this way?

Comment: @Rakesh I know what label is ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think your attribute (column) name is "comment" and your are trying to pass the "comments".

So it should be

Change in controller

```
def contact_params
    params.require(:contact).permit(:name, :email, :comment)
  end
```

Change in views

```
<div class="form-group">
     <%= f.label :comments %>
     <%= f.text_area :comment, class: 'form-control' %>
 </div>
```